# Counter Flip Flop D no sequence

Tags: flipflop, counter

I have the sequence: 0-3-1-2-3-1.
Making the table for this.

|Present state    | Next state | D1| D0 |

|  0    0         |  1   1     | 1 | 1  |

|  0    1         |  1   0     | 1 | 0  |

|  1    0         |  1   1     | 1 | 1  |

|  0    1         |  0   1     | 0 | 1  |

In kmap i get :
D0 = ~Q1 + Q0.

D1 = ~Q0 + ~Q1.

But, my sequence is incorrect when I set up the circuit. What was my mistake? Thank you in advance.

*I don't know if I was clear on the issue, but the image of the sequence

[image]

Comment: Your sequence repeats every six elements, but you only have four states. You'll need to actually have six states, that are mapped to the outputs 0, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1 with some logic function. Otherwise, there's no way, based on the current state alone, to tell apart the 1->0 and 1->2 transitions that occur after the third and sixth states, if your states are just the 0,1,2,3.

Comment: Do I need to add two more mappings to my table?
Excuse me for my confusion. Did not quite understand.

Comment: You'd need at least six states, with three flip-flops (which can represent up to eight states). One example mapping would be to count 0,3,1,6,7,5, and output only the two lowest bits of the state as the result; another would be to count 0,1,2,3,4,5 and have combinational logic that translates the state to the values 0,3,1,2,3,1.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still a little confused as to how to work with the 6 states, but it's something to start thinking about.

Comment: Same way -- you'd kmap them in a 4x2 kmap, and you'd need three state variables.

Comment: Will I make a kmap for the sequence 031675 and another kmap for 012345? I'm thinking that for other sequences that I will have to use don't care in kmap

Comment: I gave you two example mappings. You can either make your state transition K-maps that count 0,3,1,6,7,5, and just use the lower two bits for the output, or *as another independent solution for your design goal* you can have state transition K-maps that count 0,1,2,3,4,5 and *another* set of k-maps that maps 0,1,2,3,4,5 to 0,3,1,2,3,1.

Comment: Thanks. I believe I need to study more, because I am not able to connect how to use 0,1,2,3,4,5 as a way to arrive in the sequence 0,3,1,2,3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last present state in the table should be 11 not 01.

That makes

D0 = ~Qo + Q1

Comment: I actually missed the last value in the table present state, but do you talk about D1 and D0 that should be 11?

Comment: I was confused how to get that answer

Comment: Please don't give out solutions to obvious homework problems. Pointing out an error is one thing, but working out the equation for the OP is further than I would like to go.

Comment: I redid the kmap and understood my mistake. Thanks